# bash, text file remove all text in each line before the last space

Tags: bash, awk, sed, space

I have a file with a format like this:

```
First Last UID
First Middle Last UID
```

Basically, some names have middle names (and sometimes more than one middle name). I just want a file that only as UIDs.

Is there a sed or awk command I can run that removes everything before the last space?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## awk

Print the last field of each line using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk).

The last field is indexed using the `NF` variable which contains the number of fields for each line. We index it using a dollar sign, the resulting one-liner is easy.

```
awk '{ print $NF }' file
```

## rs, cat & tail

Another way is to transpose the content of the file, then grab the last line and transpose again (this is fairly easy to see).

The resulting pipe is:

```
cat file | rs -T | tail -n1 | rs -T
```

## cut & rev

Using [cut](/questions/tagged/cut) and `rev` we could also achieve this goal by reversing the lines, cutting the first field and then reverse it again.

```
rev file | cut -d ' ' -f1 | rev
```

## sed

Using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) we simply remove all chars until a space is found with the [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) `^.* [^ ]*$`. This regex means match the beginning of the line `^`, followed by any sequence of chars `.*` and a space . The rest is a sequence of non spaces `[^ ]*` until the end of the line `$`. The sed one-liner is:

```
sed 's/^.* \([^ ]*\)$/\1/' file
```

Where we capture the last part (in between `\(` and `\)`) and sub it back in for the entire line. `\1` means the first group caught, which is the last field.

### Notes

1. As [Ed Norton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) cleverly pointed out we could simply not catch the group and remove the former part of the regex. This can be as easily achieved as

   `sed 's/.* //' file` 
   Which is remarkably less complicated and more elegant.
2. For more information see `man sed` and `man awk`.

Comment: In sed all you'd need is `sed 's/.* //'`.

Comment: Yes of course, thanks for the input, should have seen that.

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep`:

```
$ grep -o '[^[:blank:]]*$'  file
UID
UID
```

`-o` tells grep to print only the matching part.  The regex `[^[:blank:]]*$` matches the last word on the line.

Comment: Yes `grep`, great solution!